# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de guardar cadena de texto sin validar en php + mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un formulario en html + php + mysql, sin embargo el formulario tiene un cuadro de texto en el que se puede ingresar información relacionada con la experiencia laboral del candidato, dicho esto antes, los usuarios puedes ingresar una gran variedad de caracteres especiales haciendo las valiadaciones un poco complejas, ya que cada que un usuario agrega un valor nuevo que no está dentro de la valiadación se tiene que editar el código para permitir este nuevo caracter.

Actualmente utilizo para guardar:
utf8_encode($cadena);

Y para mostrar:
utf8_decode($cadena);

El problema es que con esa función no estoy tomando en cuenta los caracteres como #"#$$/()_\"", etc, etc, etc.

Lo que me gustaría es, **codificar a manera que no tenga que hacer validación** pero que tampoco tenga problema al guardar en base de datos y luego decodificar para imprimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general es buena práctica sanitizar tus strings, sin embargo con una sentencia preparada no existe el riesgo de la inyección de código en la base de datos.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Si n quieres utilizar sentencias preparadas (aunque deberías por seguridad), puedes utilizar alguno de los filtros que proporciona php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: Gracias @Alejandro Rivas, te comento que ya utilizo sentencias preparadas, sin embargo, cuando el usuario agrega una comilla o comilla doble hay problemas. Por eso preguntaba si antes de ejecutar la sentencia podría convertir o hacer un proceso para evitar este tipo de inconveniente y aceptar cualquier caracter en mi sistema.

Comment: Correcto, en ese caso sanitiza y posteriormente utiliza la sentencia preparada. Creo que podrías usar el filtro **FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS** para escapar los caracteres especiales.

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!